# ASP.NET menu control with bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-4.6

ASP.NET menu control with bootstrap does not show DynamicPopOutImage. 
I tried to show the default image or my custom one. It does not render. The menu is built from a database.

```
   <div style="float:left">
    <asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server" 
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        RenderingMode="List"
        IncludeStyleBlock="false"
        StaticDisplayLevels="1"                           
        DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="true"                            
        DynamicPopOutImageUrl="Images/arrow.gif"
        MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3" 
        EnableViewState="false"
        CssClass="nav navbar-fix-top" 
        StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav navbar-nav" 
        StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="active"
        DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu"         
        SkipLinkText="">
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

Comment: This is ASP.NET 4.6 with vb

Answer (score 0):

Figured it

```
       <div style="float:left">
                    <asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server" 
                           Orientation="Horizontal" 
                           EnableViewState="false"
                           CssClass="nav navbar-fix-top" 
                           StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="navbar " 
                           StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="active"
                           RenderingMode="List"
                           DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu"  
                           DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="dropdown"
                           StaticMenuItemStyle-HorizontalPadding="17"
                           DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="true" 
                           StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"
                          StaticMenuItemStyle-BackColor="#F5F5F5"
                          StaticMenuItemStyle-ForeColor="Black"
                          StaticMenuItemStyle-BorderStyle="Ridge"
                          StaticMenuItemStyle-BorderWidth="1"
                          StaticMenuItemStyle-BorderColor="LightGray"
                          StaticMenuStyle-VerticalPadding="5"


                         >   
                    </asp:Menu>
          </div>
```